# Laravel filter except for internal API request

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm using the HMVC package to consume my own API. However it also includes some POST requests which require authenticaton. Obviously I can't just dump in my password in the request nor do I find ENV variables an elegant solution.

Is there a way to check inside the basic auth filter whether the request is made internally?

The filter is applied to the controller, not the route

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

You could add the exception test on the filter, so that you only apply the filter rule if the request is not from localhost.

**Second option**

You would apply the filter on the Route, so that you wouldn't have problems accessing the controller locally.

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}));
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes

**Third option**

It doesn't seem an elegant solution either, but a workaroung would be to look if the request comes from localhost, you could manually authenticate the user.

```
$user = User::find(1);
Auth::login($user);
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually